# Replace response body with NGINX

Tags: authentication, nginx

I have to configure Nginx in such a way that it will respond to a fixed request url:

```
/some/url/search
```

with the specified response body, for example:

```
{
    "user" : "John"
    "hits":
        [
            {
               "id" : 1,
               "data" : "Some data"

            }
        ]
}
```

Moreover, the field `"user"` in response body should be changed according to the authenticated user. In the case above it is assumed that user 'John' is authenticated.

Here is the part of my current Nginx config:

```
    server {
           listen 8000;

           location /some/url/search {
                  auth_basic "Please prolvide your login and password";
                  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
                  ...
           }
    }
```

I don't know how to place statement to use instead of three dots to return the mentioned response body considering authenticated user's name. Is it possible with Nginx?

**Problem**

I'm trying to implement authorization mechanism for Kibana dashboards. When a user clicks on "Show dashboards" button, the app sends request to a URL (let it be `/some/url/search`) to obtain all dashboards, and the response looks like the mentioned above. I want to replace this response somehow with predefined list of dashboards available to a user according to his login.

Comment: Where is this response body comes from?

Comment: From a file, for instance.

Comment: For a file you could use SSI

Comment: Thanks. So I have several files, each corresponds to a user. How to configure Nginx to return a special file when a particular user is authenticated?

Comment: May be you describe the real problem you try to solve? I don't understand how you come from «replace user in file» to «several files correspondent to user»

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna edit the question.